# Show and hide dt & dd on hover

Tags: javascript

I'm using a toggle class for `dd & dt` it is working fine But I want to show & hide on hover how to use this?

```
<div class="navigation">
                    <dt><?php echo $this->__($_filter->getName()) ?></dt>
                    <dd><?php echo $_filter->getHtml() ?></dd>
                </div>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery=$.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('.navigation dd').hide(); 

        jQuery('.navigation dt').click(function(){ 
                jQuery(this).next('dd').slideToggle('slow');
                jQuery(this).toggleClass('glace_navigationlayer-collapsed'); 


            });


     }); 
    </script>
```

Comment: Have you looked at the examples in the jQuery documentation for [the .hover() method](http://api.jquery.com/hover)?

Comment: No can you please suggest some example but i need to dd & dt not div class i already seen div

Comment: It doesn't matter what the element types are.

Comment: Could you show us your html code?

Comment: Check my updated question

Comment: So you want to hide `.navigation dd` when `.navigation dt` is hovered on?

Comment: Yes if i hover dt then only dd should show otherwise it's hide

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use Javascript to show and hide elements on hover. CSS will be a better choice.

```css
.navigation dt:hover + dd {
  display: none;
}


/*Don't care about this code*/
.navigation dt {
  background-color: red;
}
.navigation dd {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation">
  <dt>dt</dt>
  <dd>dd</dd>
</div>
```

The `+` selector will select the next sibling. It means that you must place `dd` after `dt`.

Answer (score 0):

```
.toggledClass{
   display: none; 
 }
```

You can use the native `.hover()` function...this takes two callbacks, first what you want to do on mouse-enter, second what you want to do on mouse-leave.

```
$('.navigation').hover(addYourClass, removeYourClass)

function addYourClass(){
     $('.navigation').addClass('toggledClass')
}

function removeYourClass(){
     $('.navigation').removeClass('toggledClass')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This must be very straight forward. Not sure why the below code won't work for you.

```js
var $ = jQuery;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.navigation dd').hide(); 

  $('.navigation dt').hover(function(){ 
    $(this).next('dd').stop(true).slideToggle('slow');
    $(this).toggleClass('glace_navigationlayer-collapsed'); 
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navigation">
  <dt>YOUR DT</dt>
  <dd>YOUR DD</dd>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks it's working fine how to add same thing into dropdown also

Comment: I don't get it. Do you want to hide the dropdown on hover, or show the items of dropdown on hover? Both doesn't seem like a normal behavior to me.

Comment: i have a dropdown onclick only it's show i need on hover

Comment: You can use the same method as above. Just replace the `.navigation dt` with the element `classname, id or tagname` you are hovering, and write the code to show dropdown inside it.

Comment: I can't able to select click dd values check your example also same

Comment: You need click and hover at the same time? Is that what you want?

Comment: On hover it show some item on that i need to selet to any one option

Answer (score -1):

Try [mouseenter](https://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [mouseleave](https://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/).

```js
jQuery('.navigation dd').hide();
jQuery('.navigation dt').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
  jQuery(this).next('dd').slideToggle('slow');
  jQuery(this).toggleClass('glace_navigationlayer-collapsed');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<dl class="navigation">
  <dt>Chrome</dt>
  <dd>by Google</dd>
  <dt>Safari</dt>
  <dd>by Apple</dd>
<dl>
```